# Counting how many positive numbers are in list (NIL is not a number?)

Tags: lisp

I have a list: `(setq listy '(4 -3 8 99 -40 61 12 -8 2 -20))`

My function `lenPos` should find the length of all positive numbers in list (i.e. 6). However, I'm getting this error:

```
*** - +: NIL is not a number
```

I'm checking if my list is null prior to doing any number-checking in the if statements. So I don't understand where the error is coming from.

```
;num of positive elems
(defun lenPos (list)
    (cond
        ((null list) 0) ;if null list return 0
        (t (cond ;else
            ((> (car list) 0) (+ 1 (lenPos (cdr list))))
        ))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `list` isn't `null`, and the first element isn't positive, then the function does not explicitly return anything, so implicitly returns `nil`.

Comment: Yup. In the nested-if I needed an else statement: (t (+ 0 (lenPos (cdr list))))